# asp.net authentication and authorisation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Form authentication. Here I am using a login control and in (login.cs) control I am calling the following method to validate the user. Here I am using local name for both username and password and now I want to connect to the database so I can retrieve username and password.

```
private bool Authenticateme(string username, string password, bool remberusername)
{
    String localusername = "username";
    String localpassword = "amar";
    if (username.Equals(localusername) && password.Equals(localpassword))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [the MemberShip and Role Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354509.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `OnAuthenticate` by adding it like this:

```
<asp:Login OnAuthenticate="AuthenticateEventHandler" />
```

Add event handler in .cs file like this

```
private void OnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    bool Authenticated = false;
    Authenticated = SiteSpecificAuthenticationMethod(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);

    e.Authenticated = Authenticated;
}
```

implement `SiteSpecificAuthenticationMethod` that will validate user against database.

Here are the reference links:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx
2. http://forums.asp.net/t/1403132.aspx

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following and create a SQL Server database with field username and password

```
SQlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Database connection string");
const string uName="UserName";
const string pWord="Password";
public bool getAuthenticate(string UserName,string Password)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(con);
    SQlParameter[] param=new SqlParameter[]{
         new SqlParamter(uName,UserName),
         new SqlParameter(pWord,Password)
    };
    cmd.Parameters.AddRanage(param);
    SqlDataReader rd;
    rd = cmd.executeReader();

    if(rd.read())
    {
         con.Close();
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
         con.Close();
         return false;
    }
}
```